# What can be considered as a better Architecture for having common styles across multiple projects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Project structure is as follows:

[image]

I have Styles.xaml defined within WPFStyles project. These styles are being used by project1, project2, 3 and 4 using PACK URI.

Is this the best way to share styles across multiple projects?

Comment: Asking what's the "best" way to do anything is *Primarily Opinion Based* and thus off-topic for StackOverflow. Can you elaborate? what's wrong with your current approach? which specific pain points would you like to alleviate?

Comment: Apologies if the question is not put in proper way.
With this approach, WPFStyles project has to be referenced in each of other projects. In addition,  PACK URI is used in all xamls to reference styles in WPFStyles.

Is there a way to specify this PACK URI reference in one place (like in parent project CSharp) and have the xaml styles available in all projects without using PACK URI in all of them?

Comment: Yes, that's the standard way to do it. For example if your applications have the [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/) theming, then you need to reference `MahApps.Metro.dll` in your projects. Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Add your resource references in `Application.Resources`, not on each XAML file.

Comment: That would work better! Thanks @HighCore